# How to insert a snippet without using completionItem / autocomplete

Tags: monaco-editor

I would like to programmatically and dynamically insert a snippet (such as `<foo attr="$1">$2</foo>`. Checking the docs it seems like the only way to use snippets is in completion item providers (returning a completion item with `kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Snippet`). I've found also a `SnippetString` interface but the only place where it is supported is, again, in a `CompletionItem`.

I was also wondering that maybe I could make a `CompletionItem` to be triggered programmatically but I didn't find a way to do that. I tried with `editor.executeEdits()` where you can pass identifiers of actions, but I don't see a way to identify a `CompletionItem`.

Comment: I have the same problem with the hover provider, they are either strings or MarkedDownStrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate typing snippet in editor as:

```
    let text = "foo"; //snippet label
    this.editor.trigger('keyboard', 'editor.action.triggerSuggest', {});
    this.editor.trigger('keyboard', 'type', {text: text});
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.editor.trigger('editor', 'acceptSelectedSuggestion', {});
    }, 100);
```

setTimeout required for the editor to load snippets

Answer (score 0):

What about registernig a custom action or custom command and adding the text when user do some gesture / key combination ? See :

- https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-adding-a-command-to-an-editor-instance - in that case you will have to implement the select list or whatever you want to use.

I think code completion is the right way to go. Why don't use that? 
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example